# Installing ffmpeg through homebrew: dyld library not loaded

Tags: homebrew

After installing ffmpeg through homebrew without any errors and after confirming that it has been linked, I get the following error when trying to run it:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libopenh264.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/miniconda3/lib/libavcodec.58.54.100.dylib
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      ffmpeg
```

I've tried it through pip, conda, the ffmpeg.org website, all to no avail. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you using Homebrew (the reference to /opt looks odd)?

Comment: What version of macOS have you got. The homebrew build is bad it has picked up stuff from conda which it should not do. That looks like a bug in homebrew

Comment: What was the exact hombrew command you used - Given https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/macOS#ffmpegthroughHomebrew the install is not a simple one "Since v2.0, Homebrew does not offer options for its core formulae anymore. Users who want to build ffmpeg with additional libraries (including non-free ones) need to use so-called taps from third party repositories. These repositories are not maintained by Homebrew. "

Comment: I had tried to install it through homebrew several times before, and brew uninstall wasn't enough, I guess. Before homebrew, I had also tried with pip, and conda, and both of them failed (for context, I only need ffmpeg as a dependency for a Python package that uses this aspect of Matplotlib's functionality). So I thought I was doomed, but I finally got rid of everything, followed [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zl4vo0dhLRk&lc=UgxmKR8LGlwVkqW2klh4AaABAg.9HZwJEAJeNr9HciKYlcenl) instructions and it worked!

Comment: ffmpeg isn't working because the dynamic linker found a copy of libavcodec **not** installed by Homebrew before it found the one installed by Homebrew.  This is not **specifically** Homebrew's problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't offer anything to help you w/ Homebrew. I gave it up some time ago due to various issues like this. I can recommend [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) as a package manager for macOS.

Once you have MacPorts installed, you should be able to install a functional copy of `ffmpeg`. I installed `ffmpeg` on my macOS Catalina system some time ago, and use it regularly without a hitch. Following is the `port` command I used:

```
% sudo port install ffmpeg +nonfree
```

`nonfree` was one of the "variants" available for `ffmpeg`; variants are explained [here on the MacPorts site](https://guide.macports.org/#using.variants)

Comment: Note that `+nonfree` will explicitly cause ffmpeg to be built from source for legal reasons. Which is 100% okay if OP wants nonfree libraries, but I'm trying to fight the misconception of "MacPorts builds everything from source." 

Comment: @Wowfunhappy The ffmpeg port was especially twitchy during the move from Python 3.8 to 3.9... MacPorts did not coordinate that well at all and dependencies would cause even the GPL port to be rebuilt.

Answer (score -1):

try to do this - I am installing ffmpeg from separate casks

```
brew upgrade --force   homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg --fetch-HEAD --with-fdk-aac --with-libbluray --with-openh264 --with-srt --with-wavpack --with-webp --with-xvid --with-two-lame --with-opencore-amr --with-librsvg --with-openjpeg --with-openssl@1.1 --with-speex --with-openssl --with-xvid
```

I encounter that problem when trying to compile pianobar. Reason for that is pianobar has main ffmpeg in its dependencies than this functional one. so you have to find formula on your system e.g.

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/pianobar.rb
/usr/local/Cellar/pianobar/2020.11.28_1/.brew/pianobar.rb
```

you will see

```
class Pianobar < Formula
  desc "Command-line player for https://pandora.com"
  homepage "https://github.com/PromyLOPh/pianobar/"
  url "https://6xq.net/pianobar/pianobar-2020.11.28.tar.bz2"
  sha256 "653bfb96b548259e3ac360752f66fdb77e8e220312e52a43c652f7eb96e7d4fe"
  license "MIT"
  revision 1
  head "https://github.com/PromyLOPh/pianobar.git"

  depends_on "pkg-config" => :build
  depends_on "ffmpeg"
  depends_on "json-c"
  depends_on "libao"
  depends_on "libgcrypt"

  uses_from_macos "curl"

  def install
    # Discard Homebrew's CFLAGS as Pianobar reportedly doesn't like them
    ENV["CFLAGS"] = "-O2 -DNDEBUG " +
                    # Or it doesn't build at all
                    "-std=c99 " +
                    # build if we aren't /usr/local'
                    "#{ENV.cppflags} #{ENV.ldflags}"
    system "make", "PREFIX=#{prefix}"
    system "make", "install", "PREFIX=#{prefix}"

    prefix.install "contrib"
  end

  test do
    require "pty"
    PTY.spawn(bin/"pianobar") do |stdout, stdin, _pid|
      stdin.putc "\n"
      assert_match "pianobar (#{version})", stdout.read
    end
  end
end
```

I modify the line `depends_on "ffmpeg"` to `depends_on "homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg"` and repeat that for `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/pianobar.rb`
then I force reinstall of pianobar. Should work. If not, then check if binary you need is linked to the older version of library.

I really hope someone one helps me write own package manager maybe in Swift instead of Ruby that will be based on Gentoo's Portage philosophy.

Comment: Can you edit the answer down to the actual answer part? The rant about Homebrew kind of makes it difficult to see the relevant parts.